# HTTP - 400 bad request while downloading file

Tags: php, apache, lamp, kohana-3

After further investigation on [basis of previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987667/url-decoding-not-working-as-expected) url encode/decode is working properly. Issue is something with Apache server (might be) which serves file download request
Specially if my file name ends with % sign, it fails.
For e.g.

```
Original File name:

204153_20090605_Aluminiumacetotartraat_DCB_oordruppels_1,2%.pdf 



Url in browser after clicking on download link:

http://pdf/204153_20090605_Aluminiumacetotartraat_DCB_oordruppels_1%2C2%25.pdf
```

This returns 400 error with bad request. I am using LAMP with Kohana 3 framework.

Please guide.

Thanks is advance.

Comment: If you have access to it, look into the server's `error.log` to get more info about the request

Comment: error.log doesn't show any error related to this bad request. Now confusing is it related to apache or browser or Kohana?

Comment: please provide the Apache log for an error entry. Rule of thumb, if Apache log exits with code 200 and you get a code 400 on browser it's Kohana's own doing that triggering the errors.

Answer (score -1):

You missed a Host in the address.
If it's only tipping fault the server may does not have permissions to access the file.

Comment: I have removed Host to shorten a link. Other files at same repository can be accessed without any problem. So issue of permission.

Comment: Sorry meant typing. May it's twice decoded. This would cause a problem if there is a '%' again, but not without.

Comment: Even though, if you directly put address in browser http://pdf/204153_20090605_Aluminiumacetotartraat_DCB_oordruppels_1,2%.pdf, it results in bad request only.

Comment: This is because the browser forwards to pdf.com. I think this not what you want. Anyway encoded url (%25 instead %) gives 404 Not found.